# How to exclude a set of elements in R?

Tags: r, extract

I have two data frames: `A` and `B` of the same number of columns names and content. Data frame `B` is the subset of `A`. I want to get `A` without `B`. I have tried different functions like `setdiff`, `duplicated`, `which` and others. None of them worked for me, perhaps I didn't use them correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add what you tried to the question

Comment: In addition, provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Do your data.frames have a column that's a unique identifier?  If not, create one and the it should be pretty trivial using the `%in%` operator and `[]` selection or `subset`.

Comment: Thank you all for showing interest. digEmAll
 has answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `merge` e.g.:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c('A','B','C','D','E'),col2=1:5,col3=11:15)
subset <- df1[c(2,4),]

subset$EXTRACOL <- 1 # use a column name that is not present among 
                     # the original data.frame columns
merged <- merge(df1,subset,all=TRUE)

dfdifference <- merged[is.na(merged$EXTRACOL),]
dfdifference$EXTRACOL <- NULL

-----------------------------------------
> df1:
  col1 col2 col3
1    A    1   11
2    B    2   12
3    C    3   13
4    D    4   14
5    E    5   15

> subset:
  col1 col2 col3
2    B    2   12
4    D    4   14

> dfdifference:
  col1 col2 col3
1    A    1   11
3    C    3   13
5    E    5   15
```

Comment: Thank you digEmAll, this answered my question.

Comment: Good answer: you could clean it up a bit (says Mr.OCD) with `dfdifference <- merged[is.na(merged$EXTRACOL),1:(dim(merged)[2]-1)]`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: yes, you're right that would save the last line. But I'd prefer to not rely on columns order and go for something like: `dfdifference <- merged[is.na(merged$EXTRACOL),!colnames(merged) %in% c('EXTRACOL')]`